# Nothing shows up in datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using datagrid view. Data gets added in the table and from the watch window, I can see that there is 1 row included in table but nothing gets displayed in datagrid.

Here is the code:

```
 DataTable PopulateDataGrids(DataGrid grid, List<RetrievedEmailData> data)
 {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Sr No");
            table.Columns.Add("Company Name");
            table.Columns.Add("Email");

            int count = 0;

            DataRow row;

            foreach (RetrievedEmailData item in data)
            {
                count++;
                row = table.NewRow();
                row["Sr No"] = count.ToString();
                row["Company Name"] = item.Name;
                row["Email"] = item.Email;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

This is the method call:

```
dataGridBoatCompanyList.DataContext = PopulateDataGrids(dataGridBoatCompanyList, boat);
```

XAML markup:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="322" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="dataGridBoatCompanyList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding  `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` to your grid

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="322" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="dataGridBoatCompanyList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" />
```

also, you in your method, `PopulateDataGrids()` the first parameter is not being used. If all you are trying to do is populate the grid then you can skip that method and just use

```
dataGridBoadCompanyList.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<RetrievedEmailData>(boat);
```

EDIT:

If I try this

```
void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            dataGridBoatCompanyList.ItemsSource =
                new ObservableCollection<RetrievedEmailData>(new[]
                                                                 {
                                                                     new RetrievedEmailData
                                                                         {Email = "dfsd", Name = "fadsfds"}
                                                                 });
        }
```

and

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="322" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,6,0,0" Name="dataGridBoatCompanyList" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" />
```

I get a populated list like this

[image]

Comment: using your method o observed that DataContext contains the data but it is still not showing up

Comment: @Afnan try usint ItemsSource instead of DataContext both in XAML and code behind.

Comment: I also get it populated now.Can i ask you favor to please explain me the concept of ObservableCollection.Like till now i have always used datatable and all that stuff to populate the grid but i am loving this how this does the job in one line

Comment: @Afnan Here's a nice MSDN [post on ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd252944.aspx?pr=blog). The example code is in VB but it's pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to tell without seeing the XAML definition of your DataGrid, but maybe you mean to do

```
dataGridBoatCompanyList.ItemsSource = PopulateDataGrids(dataGridBoatCompanyList, boat);
```

Comment: added my XML
on changing what you say it gives error 
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataTable' to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)